# How to do a timeline graph similar to GitHub using D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, timeline, brush

GitHub uses D3 library for its graphs but I can't find any sample similar to how GitHub deals with timeline.

GitHub allows the user to select a particular period in time within the graph and then it shows data specific to that period.

Any example of the "period selection" ("brush") with D3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the example I was looking for:

http://bl.ocks.org/1667367